# Class inheritance with constructors results in NoneType

Tags: python-3.x, class, inheritance

I'm trying to create a class `Child` which inherits from class `Parent`. The class `Parent` uses constructors calling subclass `Child1` for its instanciation.

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self):
        print("use the constructor")

    @classmethod
    def constructor(self, arg1, kind='child1'):
        for cls in self.__subclasses__():
            if cls.istype(kind):
                return cls(arg1)

class Child1(Parent):
    def __init__(self,arg1):
        self.arg1 = arg1

    @staticmethod
    def istype(kind):
        return kind == 'child1'


class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

test1 = Parent.constructor(1)

test2 = Child.constructor(1)
```

In the above example, when I'm doing an instance `test1` :

```
test1 = Parent.constructor(1)
type(test1)
```

results in `__main__.Child1`, which is fine.
However, when I'm doing an instance `test2` :

```
test1 = Child.constructor(1)
type(test2)
```

results in `NoneType`. 
How to make `test2` be of type of `__main.__Child1`, without touching `Parent` and `Child1` definition ?

Thank you

Comment: Is this an oversimplified example? why don't you just use `super().__init__()` in `Child.__init__`?

Comment: I just tried your proposition, using `super().__init__()` in `Child.__init__` but it does not seem to work. Yes the example is simplified. `Parent` and `Child1` are from a package that I don't won't to modify.

Comment: as a fact, `super().__init__` works. If it doesn't in your case you will have to update your question and show exactly how you used it. It is more likely that you used it wrong rather than it "not working"

Comment: I've updated the question to show how I used it.